# How can I use the Aramex API with WSDL and Python 3.6?

Tags: xml, python-3.x, aramex

I found some PHP and python example code about the Aramex Shipping services and their shipping API on their website. I'm testing my API credentials, but I'm getting the error below.

[Exemple python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741512/how-can-i-use-the-aramex-api-with-wsdl-and-python)

but the lib ' suds ' not supported for python 3.6 in found the 'zeep' lib but i didn't work with it :/

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You the aramex rest api, if it you are unable to use the soap method.
https://www.getpostman.com/collections/451f0e7e6a1c0caa23b8